# sqlsrvr.exe is not using all memory

Tags: sql-server, memory

I have no clue what to set up more.
I tried a lot.

My Problem is that on my test Server everything is runing perfectly see 
[image]

but on my production Server its not! see 
[image]

I found this on my Production Server:
"Using locked pages for buffer pool"

This is shown in the error log of the SQL Server.
This line only Shows up in the production System.

Both Systems are SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise with WIN2K8 R2 both in 64 bit.

Locked Pages in Memory is not enabled in GPEDIT.MSC

Can someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/address-windowing-extensions) allocated pages are not reported by Task Manager. The "[Using locked pages for buffer pool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb970070-support-for-locked-pages-on-sql-server-standard-edition-64-bit-systems-388ddbde-1713-5e2b-4d96-8711499db3ef)" message means the production server is using AWE. Do not trust Task Manager. Use SQL Server own counters: [SQL Server, Memory Manager Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-memory-manager-object?view=sql-server-ver16), [SQL Server, Buffer Manager Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance-monitor/sql-server-buffer-manager-object?view=sql-server-ver16).

Read [Fun with Locked Pages, AWE, Task Manager, and the Working Set…](https://web.archive.org/web/20151121055642/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/psssql/archive/2009/09/11/fun-with-locked-pages-awe-task-manager-and-the-working-set.aspx)

Comment: I recommend you read the articles I linked. They explain everything well beyond 'nice try'.

Comment: I dont want to read articles about  Locked Pages since this is not my issue, or is it?

Comment: Thanks Phillip, you just made my day, I literally burst into laugh.

Comment: as far as i know "locked Pages in Memmory" aka "LPIM" as set in the gpedit. This is not set. So the Locked Pages should not be the issue or do i get something wrong here. Furthermore as far as I understood it, enable LPIM would increase virtual disk Memory or is it the otherway around. Furhtermore on the test System the LPIM is not enabled either. So again as far a I understand it, they should behave the same way?!?!?

Comment: LPIM is a privilege that is already granted to certain accounts (eg. Local System). If the engine prints that in the errorlog, it means it successfully enabled the privilege. I must trust the engine message more than anything you say, sry. If LPIM is enabled, the engine will use AWE methods to allocate memory that the Task Manager does not report. For a correct view, just look at the SQL Server's own counters, as I suggested.

Comment: Ok this is the key you just said. Please have a look at the Screenshot above. The test System runs under a seperate Domain user. The Production System runs as local System. Is this the issue?

Comment: OK this was it. I added the user as in test Environment a now this is working perfectly. Thanks for the last post! By the way, this is not said in the articals you posted! :) I am glad I made you day! :)

Comment: *Read this blog post first which gives details on the algorithm in the engine for enabling AWE or for enabling “Locked Pages”* and links to [Do I have to assign the Lock Pages in Memory privilege for Local System?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2007/10/18/do-i-have-to-assign-the-lock-privilege-for-local-system.aspx)

Comment: Or the KB970070 which I linked that states "Make sure that the service account for SQL Server has the Lock Pages in Memory privilege enabled. You do not have to set these permissions if the SQL Server Service Account is the LOCAL SYSTEM account."...

Comment: thanks anyway. its working now! You will get a green star :)